# CodeIgniter form_open call controller function with argument

Tags: php, forms, function, codeigniter, controller

How could be possible something like this:

The standard of form syntax is:

```
<?php echo form_open('controller_name/function_name');?>
```

But I have came to moment when I need to make form controller function with argument which would look something like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('controller_name/function_name(argument_name)');?>
```

I searched on google but I couldn't find any solutions for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you put those arguments into hidden fields:

**Adding Hidden Input Fields**

Hidden fields can be added by passing an associative array to the third parameter, like this:

```
$hidden = array('username' => 'Joe', 'member_id' => '234');

echo form_open('email/send', '', $hidden);
```

The above example would create a form similar to this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/email/send">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="Joe" />
<input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="234" />
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this?

```
echo form_open($form_action, $attributes);
```

If not, please clarify what you mean with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
<?php
 echo form_open('controller_name/function_name/{$arg_1}/{$arg_2}')
?>
```

and your controller as usual will have the

```
  class controller_name extends CI_Controller {
     function function_name($arg_i, $arg_2) {
        //function content
     }
  }
```